# Swift Regex matching fails when source contains unicode characters

Tags: regex, swift, xcode6, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to do a simple regex match using NSRegularExpression, but I'm having some problems matching the string when the source contains multibyte characters:

```
let string = "D 9"

// The following matches (any characters)(SPACE)(numbers)(any characters)
let pattern = "([\\s\\S]*) ([0-9]*)(.*)"

let slen : Int = string.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

var error: NSError? = nil

var regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators, error: &error)

var result = regex?.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(string, options: nil, range: NSRange(location:0,
length:slen), withTemplate: "First \"$1\" Second: \"$2\"")
```

The code above returns "D" and "9" as expected

If I now change the first line to include a UK 'Pound' currency symbol as follows:

```
let string = "£ 9"
```

Then the match doesn't work, even though the `([\\s\\S]*)` part of the expression should still match *any* leading characters.

I understand that the `£` symbol will take two bytes but the wildcard leading match should ignore those shouldn't it?

Can anyone explain what is going on here please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift and its regex engine, but in general I would be terribly surprised to find that `\s\S` isn't equivalent to `.` when Unicode is involved. Why aren't you using `.*` in the first grouping? That said, I'm not entirely convinced that tha's where the problem is, either; I think it's more likely that `[0-9]` fails to match unicode digits than that `\S` fails to match arbitrary non-space unicode characters.

Comment: Swift *does* support the `\d` character class, so why are you using `[0-9]`? If you try matching with `(.*) (\d*)(.*)`, do you get a match?

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I was using \s\S because of a mis-reading of an article about misuse of the '.' character. I've changed it to "(.*) (\d*)(.*)" but it still fails to match. I'm beginning to suspect it is a bug in the Swift implementation - any other character matches OK - E.g. "D$+@ 9" but when I put a '£' symbol anywhere in the string to be matched, it fails!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be confusing. The first parameter of `stringByReplacingMatchesInString()` is mapped from `NSString` in
Objective-C to `String` in Swift, but the `range:` parameter is still
an `NSRange`. Therefore you have to specify the range in the units
used by `NSString` (which is the number of UTF-16 code points):

```
var result = regex?.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(string,
        options: nil,
        range: NSRange(location:0, length:(string as NSString).length),
        withTemplate: "First \"$1\" Second: \"$2\"")
```

Alternatively you can use `count(string.utf16)`
instead of `(string as NSString).length` .

Full example:

```
let string = "£ 9"

let pattern = "([\\s\\S]*) ([0-9]*)(.*)"
var error: NSError? = nil
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern,
        options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.DotMatchesLineSeparators,
        error: &error)!

let result = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(string,
    options: nil,
    range: NSRange(location:0, length:(string as NSString).length),
    withTemplate: "First \"$1\" Second: \"$2\"")
println(result)
// First "£" Second: "9"
```

Comment: Thank you Martin - that does explain why the length of the string containing the currency symbol was being reported as 4 rather than 3. It reports the length correctly now, but the expression still doesn't match I'm afraid.

Comment: My apologies Martin - must be too early in the morning - your solution DID work!! Many thanks!! :-)

Comment: Thank you soo much! I spent so much time trying to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a couple times and Martin's answer helped me understand the problem. Here's a quick version of the solution that worked for me.

If your regular expression function includes a range parameter built like this:

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: yourString.count)
```

You can change it to this:

```
NSRange(location: 0, length: yourString.utf16.count)
```