# Swift Regular Expression Special Characters

Tags: regex, swift, locale, file-handling

I'm currently using a regular expression to find some files my app previously created, but I have problems with german "Umlauten" like ö,ä,ü. My expression doesn't match if there are "Umlaute" in the string. I guess it has something to do with the locale, but I can't figure it out what locale to set (already tried nil).

Here's some code:

```
// Building the regex
var regex = somePrefix + "_("
for string in stringArray{     
     regex += string + "|"  // string can contain öäü
}
regex.remove(at: regex.index(before: regex.endIndex))
regex += ")_w\\d_d\\d"

// Finding files
let fileManager = FileManager()
let files = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: somePath)
while let file = files?.nextObject() {
   let fileName = file as! String            
   if fileName.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: Locale.current) != nil {
   print(fileName + " found")
   }
}
```

// Some example that didn't match:

```
Regex = reis 8_(Ibedir|Drölf )_w\d_d\d
Filename that didnt match = reis 8_Drölf _w0_d0.plist
```

Comment: This might help, those characters are unicode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756530/swift-regex-matching-fails-when-source-contains-unicode-characters

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of a file name and a pattern which does not match as expected?

Comment: @MartinR i added an example

Comment: It could be a Unicode normalization issue. Try adding `.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` to the filename and/or the pattern.

Comment: Adding it to both did the trick. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the file names use a different Unicode normalization form than
the given strings. The [Unicode Regular Expression Guidelines: 3.2 Canonical Equivalents](https://unicode.org/reports/tr18/tr18-5.1.html#Canonical%20Equivalents) suggest:

> Before (or during) processing, translate text (and pattern) into a normalized form. This is the simplest to implement, since there are available code libraries for doing normalization.

This can be achieved by applying `.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`
to both the pattern and the file name.